# Can I disable the renaming behaviour in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, rename

When you click a file or folder name in Explorer, that object gets selected. But if it is already selected, Windows thinks you want to rename it. I find this annoying, because almost always that is *not* what I want. Maybe I wanted to select it and didn't notice that it was already selected, or, more often, I tried to doubleclick to open the object and I wasn't fast enough.

I know that I can change the doubleclick threshold, and I know that I can proceed without renaming in various ways. It's a small annoyance, but I would like to do away with it.

Basically, if I click on an object that is already selected, I would like nothing to happen. If I do want to rename an object, which is much rarer than wanting to select it or open it, I would be quite happy to rightclick and choose rename, or use F2.

Comment: I assume you know that Esc key takes you out of the rename, still annoying though.

Comment: You could go to settings>Devices>mouse>additional mouse options(it is a hyperlink) and set double click speed to your comfort range. This is how I came around my problem. Even google search results aren't that satisfying...